# Android ViewModel is not destroyed when fragment is destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I have view model in my fragment created using the following code:

```
 areaViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this, AreaViewModelFactory(AreaController.repository, currentPanelId, areaId)
    )[AreaViewModel::class.java]
```

Implementation of ViewModel and ViewModelFactory:

```
class AreaViewModelFactory (private val repository: AreaRepository): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(AreaViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return AreaViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}

class AreaViewModel@Inject constructor(private val repository: AreaRepository) : ViewModel(){

companion object {
    const val TAG: String = "AreaViewModel"
}

init {
    Log.i("AreaViewModel", "AreaViewModel created!")
}

private val _areaState = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Area>>(Resource.loading(null))
val areaState: StateFlow<Resource<Area>>
    get() = _areaState

fun getAreaById(panelId: Int, areaId: Int){
    _areaState.value = Resource.loading(null)
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getAreaById(panelId, areaId) .catch { e ->
            _areaState.value = Resource.error(e.toString(), null)
        }
        .collect { it ->
            _areaState.value = Resource.success(it)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    Log.i("AreaViewModel", "AreaViewModel destroyed!")
    super.onCleared()
}
}
```

Then fragments get removed via fragment manager:

```
private void removeControlFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragmentList.size(); i++) {
        if (fragmentList.get(i) instanceof ControlFragment) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentList.get(i)).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that onCleared of ViewModel will be called when its corresponding fragment is destroyed. However this does not happen.

Please suggest what is missing or wrong?

Comment: How do you know your ControlFragment is removed? Could you share more source code for creating AreaViewModel in ControlFragment, please?

Comment: what is "this" in the ViewModelProvider? is it the Activity? if so that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

your ViewModel is holding Repo instance, so that might keep the ViewModel from being garbage collected.
Try changing Repo param to be without the keyword VAL or making it a WeakReference.